# how to use case/if else in insert on duplicate update mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql, how to use case/if else in insert on duplicate update Query format,

table t1,

```
VAL1    VAL2    TIME_STAMP
20.1    30.1    November, 07 2013 07:06:22+0000
22.1    33.1    November, 07 2013 07:07:22+0000
40.1    44.0    November, 07 2013 07:08:22+0000
```

Table t1_last (sub table of t1)

```
ID  VAL1    MIN_VAL1    MAX_VAL1    VAL2    MIN_VAL2    MAX_VAL2    TIME_STAMP
1   22.1    20.1        22.1        33.1    30.1        33.1        November, 07 2013 07:07:22+0000
```

now i want to insert  2013/11/07 07:08:22 time_stamp val1, 
val2 compare with t1_last table min_val1,max_val1,min_val2,max_val2
respectively and need to update the new value into val1,val2 and correct 
max ,min value with current time stamp.

insert or update query like:

```
id  val1    min_val1    max_val1    val2    min_val2    max_val2    time_stamp 
1   40.1    20.1        40.1        44.0    30.1        44.0        2013/11/07 07:08:22
```

Sqlfiddle link http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5be80/6

Answer (score 2):

Using on duplicate key update:-

```
INSERT INTO t1_last (id, val1, min_val1, max_val1, val2, min_val2, max_val2, time_stamp)
SELECT NULL, VAL1, VAL1, VAL1, VAL2, VAL2, VAL2, TIME_STAMP
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(TIME_STAMP) AS MaxTimeStamp FROM t1) Sub1
ON t1.TIME_STAMP = Sub1.MaxTimeStamp
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VAL1=VALUES(VAL1), 
                        MIN_VAL1=IF(MIN_VAL1 > VALUES(VAL1), VALUES(VAL1), MIN_VAL1), 
                        MAX_VAL1=IF(MAX_VAL1 < VALUES(VAL1), VALUES(VAL1), MAX_VAL1), 
                        VAL2=VALUES(VAL2),
                        MIN_VAL2=IF(MIN_VAL2 > VALUES(VAL2), VALUES(VAL2), MIN_VAL2), 
                        MAX_VAL2=IF(MAX_VAL2 < VALUES(VAL2), VALUES(VAL2), MAX_VAL2), 
                        TIME_STAMP=VALUES(TIME_STAMP);
```